# How to read all characters from file and store it in 2d array without \n?

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to read a file and store each of its character in 2d array(of size 7 by 7) without special characters like '\n' and than print that 2d array.

I write a code but it does not store and print the last line characters in 2d array.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
     char ar[7][7],c;
    int i,j;
    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen("B11.txt","r");
    if(fp==NULL)
        printf("File not Found");


for(i=0; i<7; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<7; j++)
        {

         fscanf(fp,"%c",&ar[i][j]);
        }


    }


for(i=0; i<7; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<7; j++)
        {
            printf("%c",ar[i][j]);
        }

    }
fclose(fp);
}
```

This the output of the my code:

```
abtvelo
camerag
bhtollp
qeryvxq
appboyl
awerfgh
```

But the file contains,

```
abtvelo
camerag
bhtollp
qeryvxq
appboyl
awerfgh
comsats
```

Here the file contains the word 'comsats' also, that is not printed. Why this word comsats is not printed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    for(i=0; i<7; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<7; j++)
        {
            fscanf(fp,"%c",&ar[i][j]);
        }
    }
```

`ar[i][0]` will have `\n` left out from previous line summing up to `7 \n` thus ignoring last line.

---

change  to

```
            fscanf(fp," %c",&ar[i][j]);
```

or

have `getchar()` after inner `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

The `\n` character is causing the last line to be skipped.
Change this:

```
     fscanf(fp,"%c",&ar[i][j]);
```

To this:

```
     fscanf(fp," %c",&ar[i][j]);
                ^
```

The space consumes the newline character when using `scanf()` format specifiers such as `%c %lf %d` etc.  The space is not needed however for reading strings, ( `%s` ).

Regarding your statement: *without special characters like '\n'*
If by this you are referring characters such as:

- space (" ")
- horizontal tab ("\t")
- formfeed ("\f")
- carriage return ("\r")
- vertical tab ("\v")
- and of course newline ("\n")

Consider replacing the *[fscanf()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fscanf.htm)* construct with one using *[fgetc()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgetc.htm)* in conjunction with the white-space test function: *[isspace()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_isspace.htm)*. (which checks for those characters listed above.)  Example:

```
#define ROW 7
#define COL 7
int main(void)
{
    int row = 0;
    int col = 0;
    char ar[COL][ROW];
    int byte;

    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    if(fp)
    {
        byte = fgetc(fp);
        while(byte != EOF)
        {
            if(!isspace(byte))
            {   //populate array only if not white-space
                ar[col][row++] = (char)byte;
                if(row == ROW) 
                {
                    row = 0;
                    col++;
                }
                if(col == COL) break;
            }
            byte = fgetc(fp);
        }
        fclose(fp);
    }
    // print results as in your original post...    

    return 0;
}
```